# Sync kinect audio with video stream

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

Hi i'm trying to sync audio from a kinect device and its color stream. I can get the color stream timestamp, but i cant get a timestamp for audio. The kinect documentation doesn't provide any info about the syncronism between these two streams and i would like to avoid doing an external sync unless it's absolutely necessary.

ps, im using managed code c#, but any solution using another language would be greatly aprecciated.